# How do I cancel Reinhardt's charge?

Tags: overwatch

When playing Reinhardt, sometimes I miss hitting someone with my charge ability and I'm stuck running headlong into something. Is there a way that I can stop my charge after pushing shift besides running into something or dying?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot cancel Reinhardt's Charge.   Short of running into a nearby obstacle to stop it (and that turn radius is extremely small), you either wait until you hit a wall or until your charge runs out.

Comment: In my experience, you have to hit something, I have not found there to be a range limit at which the charge "runs out".

Comment: @JamesCW There definitely is a maximum range, although it's hard to find places on the map where you charge that whole distance without hitting something. You can charge the maximum range while moving from point B to point A on Temple of Anubis and through the "carwash" on Watchpoint: Gibraltar. On the latter map, it's possible to charge towards the cliff and have your charge run out just as you reach it, sending any pinned enemies off the cliff.

Comment: New fun subgame!

Comment: @JamesCW Reinhardt bowling? I'm keen!

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish Curious now- what's the carwash on Gibraltar?